# How can I get the PropertyName of the ContainerMetadata when trying to navigate the ModelMetadata with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razorengine, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a project written using `C#` on the top of an ASP.NET Core 5 framework.

I am trying use Razor engine to manually render the `ModelMetadata` content. The `ModelMetadata` gives me a property called `ContainerMetadata` which tell me into about the parent `ModelMetadata` in the case of a complex-type property found on the parent ModelMetadata.

However, the `PropertyName` property on the `ContinerMetadata` is always null.

I have the following view-model. The `MainViewModel` bellow is passed from the controller to the view using the `View()` method.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public class CellViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class CellViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the razor view, I am access the `ModelMetadata` for the passed model using `Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata`

My goal is to be able to render the HTML manually using extension method. To get the `ModelMetadata` for each property I want to render, I use the following function

```
public static IHtmlContent GetHtml(this IHtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata)
{
    HtmlContentBuilder code = new HtmlContentBuilder();

    IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> elements = metadata.Properties.Where(metadata => metadata.ShowForDisplay);

    foreach(ModelMetadata element in elements)
    {
        if(element.IsClass) 
        {   
            // When this code is called, each proeprty on the element.ModelType has ContainerModelmetadata which is element
            // However, when I access ContainerModelmetadata.PropertyName I get null.
            var subCode = html.GetHtml(element);

            code.AppendHtml(subCode);

            continue;
        }

        code.AppendHtml(html.Editor(element.propertyName));
    }

    return code;
}
```

As you can see in the comment above, I can't seem to access the property name of the parent.

So work around this problem, I can passing the parent each time like this

```
public static IHtmlContent GetHtml(this IHtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, string parentName = null)
{
    HtmlContentBuilder code = new HtmlContentBuilder();

    IEnumerable<ModelMetadata> elements = metadata.Properties.Where(metadata => metadata.ShowForDisplay);

    foreach(ModelMetadata element in elements)
    {
        if(element.IsClass) 
        {   
            // When this code is called, each proeprty on the element.ModelType has ContainerModelmetadata which is element
            // However, when I access ContainerModelmetadata.PropertyName I get null.
            var subCode = html.GetHtml(element, element.Name);

            code.AppendHtml(subCode);

            continue;
        }

        string expression = element.propertyName;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentName)) 
        {
            expression = $"{parentName}.{element.PropertyName}";
        }

        code.AppendHtml(html.Editor(expression));
    }

    return code;
}
```

As you can see above, I have to pass the `parentName` to each level so I can get the correct expression. The problem here is that in my code, I have deeper levels, and this required for me to pass the parentName to each function. I am hoping to avoid having to pass both the Modelmetadata of the property in addition to the parentName. I am hoping to be able to get the parentName from the given `Modelmetadata` since I already have the `ContainerModelmetadata`.

How can I correctly access the value of the `PropertyName` from the `ContinerMetadata` when `ContinerMetadata` is not null?

Comment: do you think that this is enough for a stranger to understand the issue, play around with it before being able to solve it with some concrete code?

Comment: @KingKing I updated the question hoping this give you and other all the info.

Comment: why do you think the `PropertyName` must be from the `ContainerModelMetadata`? that's wrong. Actually it's from the current `ModelMetadata`, see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelmetadata.propertyname?view=aspnetcore-5.0 - There are 4 types of `ModelMetadataKind` including `Constructor`, `Property`, `Parameter` and `Type`. The `PropertyName` is null when that kind is NOT `Property`. Also the `ContainerModelMetadata` usually has `ModelMetadataKind` of `Type`, which always has `PropertyName` of null.

Comment: But in the case above, ContainerModelMetadata is a property. What is the correct way to get the expression prefix for the parent?

Comment: not sure why do you want that but at the node of `ContainerMetadata` (for `ContainerType`), the `ModelMetadataKind` is `Type` and `PropertyName` is null (not null only if `ModelMetadataKind` is `Property` but `Property` cannot be a container). In other words, it's like a dead end (no more info to travel up from that).